# Cascading dropdownlist with Json Fixed for Guid Id

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Hello everybody I need to fix a cascading dropdownlist to work with Guid Id... **It works ok with Int Id**...but I need to work with Guid Id on my tables.

When I change the type to Guid (on my models and database)... It doesn't fill the dropdownlists

please help to solved this

I got this:

**Controller**

```
  public JsonResult GetCountries()
    {           
        return Json(countries.GetAll().ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
    }


  public JsonResult GetStatesByCountryId(string countryId)
    {     
//I know, I have to convert to Guid here... the problem is in the first dropdownlist       
        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(countryId);

        var states = from s in state.GetAll() where s.CountryId == Id select s;

        return Json(states);
    }
```

**View**

```
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("dropdownCountry", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a country", new { @style = "width:250px;" })

    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:50px;">

        @Html.DropDownList("dropdownState", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a state", new { @style = "width:250px;" })

    </div>

</div>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="~/Assets/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="~/Assets/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/getcountries",
            datatype: "Json",            
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
//I think the problem is here it doesn't read Guid Numbers...when CountryId is a Guid
                    $('#dropdownCountry').append('<option value="' + value.CountryId + '">' + value.CountryName + '</option>'); 
                });
            }
        });

        $('#dropdownCountry').change(function () {
            $('#dropdownState').empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/GetStatesByCountryId",
                datatype: "Json",
                data: { countryId: $('#dropdownCountry').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $('#dropdownState').append('<option value="' + value.Id + '">' + value.StateName + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you used in the controller when you worked with GUID id's instead of ints? I suppose your parameter should be a Guid

Comment: Can you post the code where you are using Guids and where you are having trouble ? Which properties are Guid type ?

Comment: the problem is in the script

Comment: I think the problem is in the <scrip> `success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#dropdownCountry').append('<option value="' + value.CountryId + '">' + value.CountryName + '</option>');
                });`  It doesn't fill ddl if type is Guid...

Answer (score 0):

If you change your type from Id in your entity model/db to Guid, the below line will fail

```
public JsonResult GetStatesByCountryId(string countryId)
{            
    int Id = Convert.ToInt32(countryId);

}
```

Convert.ToInt32 expects an object which can be converted to a valid int (Ex : "123"). But a Guid will be like `"49e17a97-88ce-4acc-8aba-ae0c8740fd5d"` and it cannot be converted to int. So just use Guid as your param.

```
public JsonResult GetStatesByCountryId(Guid countryId)
{ 
    var states = (from s in state.GetAll() where s.CountryId == countryId  
                                                               select s).ToList();   
    return Json(states, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Assuming `state.GetAll` method returns a collection of item where it has a CountryId property of type Guid. (And the state's id's are also Guids)